# DependancyProperty attach to a property of a property

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, dependency-properties

I have a workflow with a property in it, declared like this:

```
public Person userAccount {get;set;}
```

Person is a class with it's own properties (like Person.Name) and with WF I can bind to the userAccount property fine yet I can't seem to bind to the userAccount.Name.

Is it possible to do this? If so what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and so logical just the Visual Studio editor has some issues doing it. Your path property would just need to be a set correctly.
Example (taking my scenario from above):
`Activity=BusinessProcess, Path=userAccount.Name`

Answer (score 1):

No

i don't think that its  possible to driectly bind to Memebers of Variables in Workflow

you will have to bind to entier class i.e. userAccount